# How to Display ManyToMany Field in RestFramework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Rest Framework. It is not displaying `job_users` which is `ManyToManyField` in my models. And even i want to set `job_created_by` manually when data is sended by user. And also set Current DateTime for `job_created_on`

When i am removing `job_users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)` it is giving error -

> TypeError at /api/jobs/add/
>   **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

```
class JobsAddAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
        queryset = Jobs.objects.all()
        serializer_class = JobAddSerialzer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

class JobAddSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    job_users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = [  
            'job_name', 
            'job_number',
            'job_description',
            'job_start_date',
            'job_start_time',
            'job_end_date',
            'job_end_time',
            'job_group',
            'job_users',
            'job_status',
        ]

class Jobs(models.Model):
    job_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_users = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='job_users', blank=True)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    job_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    job_created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='job_created_bys')
    job_updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    job_updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='job_updated_bys')
    job_is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    job_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you show what returns?

Comment: i have added just see

Comment: please post the JSON when the serializer is set

Comment: "TypeError at /api/jobs/add/ str returned non-string (type NoneType)" sounds like a `__str__` method is returning a `None`.

Comment: how can i tackle it if it return None Please Help

Comment: if you post the full error that would help

Comment: It is only giving TypeError

Comment: Can i use try catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a `serializer_field` to another `serailizer`. Which will populate `manytomany` field.

```
class UserSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      # your user serializer

class JobAddSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    job_users = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = [  
            'job_name', 
            'job_number',
            'job_description',
            'job_start_date',
            'job_start_time',
            'job_end_date',
            'job_end_time',
            'job_group',
            'job_users',
            'job_status',
        ]
```